# Getting only XML data with specific tags using php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to get a list of numeric IDs from an XML file. It's formatted like this.

```
<Count>Number of things found</Count>
<RetMax>Number of things asked for</RetMax>
<RetStart>0</RetStart>
<IdList>
<Id>ID#</Id>
<Id>ID#</Id>
<Id>ID#</Id>
<Id>ID#</Id>
<Id>ID#</Id>
<Id>ID#</Id>
<Id>ID#</Id>...
```

The file is generated using Esearch on the pubmed database. Is there a way using php to only get the text that is between the 'count','RetMax',and'ID' tags and have it differentiate between them? Preferably in array format.

Comment: Have you tried DOMDocument in PHP? If your document is this simple you can do so and use the PHP DOMDocument which doesn't need any plugin. http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/php-domdocument-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
echo $json->Count;
```

http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/07/26/php-convert-xml-to-json-to-array-in-an-easy-way/

Comment: Do you know of a reason this method would only work once? Most of what I do is procedural style so it might be something to do with objects but whenever I reload the page the array is empty.

Comment: may be you are not getting value in `Count` after first time? Or, show me the `$json` value you are getting.

Comment: I actually use the method from the link that you provided which gave me the array of values each with a key corresponding to the XML tag the first time but now the array is empty during subsequent reloadings of the page.

Comment: {"Count":"41","RetMax":"41","RetStart":"0","IdList":{"Id" ["22440537","21995291","21574244","21468557","21447942","21082654","21045959","20856073","20856020","20818247","20803643","20660977","20301581","20196077","20184620","19842205","19536891","19036739","18813858","18506368","18478600","18209213","18095255","17549393","17366841","17122170","16998136","16456794","16245336","16211254","16160700","15995766","15939375","15647839","15472655","15013698","14618417","12964020","12920575","12632105","12219090"]},

Comment: You should definitely get the `Count` value if you use json `echo $json->Count;`. If you are using array instead of json, then you can get the value by using `$array['Count']`

Comment: oops nevermind I was using print to check the contents of the array...which doesn't work on arrays.

Comment: Ahhaaa... you need to use `print_r` for arrays! Glad to hear it finally worked.